# Equation to find m2(slope of second line) from the tangent equation.

Tags: tangent-line, slope

We have the tangent equation

```
tan θ = (m2-m1)/(1+m1m2)
```

How to solve this to find m2?

Comment: Take the denominator to the other side, get all terms containing $m_2$ on one side, factorize $m_2$ out. Do you need a demonstration of this?

Comment: Need help on factorizing. Thats where I stumble

Comment: What kind of help? Are you unable to understand why the factorisation happens? Why $m_2-m_2m_1\tan\theta = m_2(1-m_1\tan\theta)$, for example? Or do you grasp the concept of factorisation, but don't know why it works here?

Answer (score 0):

$$\tan\theta(1+m_1m_2)=m_2-m_1$$
$$\tan\theta+m_1=m_2-m_2m_1\tan\theta$$
then complete

Comment: Need help on factorizing. Thats where I stumble

Comment: $\tan\theta+m_1=m_2(1-m_1\tan\theta)$